Bind JSON with defaults in typescript / angular
Given I have the following TypeScript class
export class OidcConfig {
    displayName: string;
    issuer: string;
    clientId: string = "app";
    sessionChecksEnabled: boolean = false;
}

Is it possible to bind the following JSON to an object of the class above, similarily how it can be bound to an interface, retaining the default values (clientId, sessionChecksEnabled) when not given in JSON?
{
   "displayName": "Keycloak",
   "issuer": "https://sso.example.com/realms/my-realm"
}

I am using Angular (13).
I tried looking around, but primarily found solutions involving interfaces (i.e. no default values), and not dealing with default values.
I tried to simply using a class instead of an interface, but it does not retain default values. If necessary I will try to build a MRE.

You can pass in the values through the constructor
export class OidcConfig {
    displayName: string;
    issuer: string;
    clientId?: string = "app";
    sessionChecksEnabled?: boolean = false;

    constructor(obj: any) {
        if(obj?.displayName) {
             this.displayName = obj.displayName;
        }
        if(obj?.issuer) {
             this.issuer= obj.issuer;
        }
    }
}
...

...
// usage
const test: OidcConfig = new OidcConfig({
   "displayName": "Keycloak",
   "issuer": "https://sso.example.com/realms/my-realm"
});

You can also use object destructuring to store the values that are present
export class OidcConfig {
    displayName: string;
    issuer: string;
    clientId: string = "app";
    sessionChecksEnabled: boolean = false;
}

const obj: any = {
   "displayName": "Keycloak",
   "issuer": "https://sso.example.com/realms/my-realm"
};
const test: OidcConfig = { ...(new OidcConfig()), ...obj };

In the above code, the properties in obj, will replace the values in the default class, thereby leaving the default properties to be present.

thx, that looks promising, but I forgot to mention I am using automatic binding from HttpClient, let me check how to apply it there. :) Edit: nvm, it's any, i.e. not yet bound.

I don't like that I need to duplicate the field names in constructor. I also realized I simplified my structure too much for the example, it's actually an object with arrays of objects, which would mean i would need to do this for every object...

@ciis0 the second approach?

true, i would save the duplication, sry for overlooking that. ^^

I have included a more complete example; but I think this changes the focus the question and I should move that to a new one...
